# Problems importing @ngrx/core @ngrx/store in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use the REDUX Pattern to build my next Angular app and for some reason I can't import the needed libraries.

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ 
      user
    })
],
```

On a fresh Angular intstall or my original app I keep getting these errors

```
ERROR in 
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (6,52): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (9,58): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (12,59): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (15,51): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (10,21): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (13,18): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (13,75): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (17,15): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (17,40): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (18,21): Generic type 'ActionReducerFactory<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts (20,20): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (15,53): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (21,40): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (22,43): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (23,43): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (12,27): Generic type 'StoreFeature<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (17,22): Generic type 'ActionReducerFactory<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (18,20): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (21,60): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (21,100): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (21,134): Generic type 'StoreConfig' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (22,84): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (22,117): Generic type 'StoreConfig' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (23,83): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store_module.d.ts (23,113): Generic type 'StoreConfig' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (6,68): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (11,61): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (16,84): Generic type 'ActionReducerMap' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (16,128): Generic type 'ActionReducerFactory<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (17,77): Generic type 'StoreFeature<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (18,26): Generic type 'StoreFeature<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_manager.d.ts (19,38): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts (21,31): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts (25,46): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/store.d.ts (25,78): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts (16,57): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts (20,57): ',' expected.
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts (20,84): Generic type 'StateActionPair' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts (20,142): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/state.d.ts (20,165): Generic type 'StateActionPair' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/reducer.d.ts (37,15): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/reducer.d.ts (37,43): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).

ERROR in C:/Users/Jason/projects/NATION5/nation5/node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/src/config.d.ts (5,14): Generic type 'ActionReducer<T, V, Action>' requires 3 type argument(s).
```

Does anybody have an Idea what this could be?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/171 : You need to have at least TypeScript 2.3 or above with version 4. TypeScript 2.4.1 along with RxJS 5.4.2 would be ideal

Comment: @JGFMK, Typescript 2.4.1 solved my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using old `angular-cli` to create the project.

- Update your @angular/cli to the latest version (`"@angular/cli": "^1.2.4"`)
- Typescript `"typescript": "~2.3.3"`
- Ngrx

  ```
  "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
  "@ngrx/effects": "^4.0.1",
  "@ngrx/store": "^4.0.0",
  ```

This is my configuration, and it's working fine for me. You can try this.

Comment: Changing from "typescript": "~2.2.0" to "typescript": "~2.3.3" works for me

Comment: Updating the global & local @angular/cli to the latest version and primarily changing the  typescript to the latest version(*) in the package.json followed by an npm install solved it for me.

Comment: I was facing the issue of "has no exported member 'environmentproviders' and it got resolved by running those commands